# how to retrieve data sent by Ajax in Cakephp?

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp

I have been stuck at this problem for a whole day. What im trying to do is to send 2 values from view to controller using Ajax.
This is my code in `hot_products` view:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();
    alert(from+" "+to);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/orders/hot_products",
        type: 'POST',

        data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to,
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

and my hot_products controller:

```
public function hot_products()
{   
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {

        $this->autoRender = false;


                    //code to get data and process it here
      }
}
```

I dont know how to get 2 values which are start_time and end_time.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.
PS: im using cakephp 2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$this->request->data` gives you the post data in your controller.

```
public function hottest_products()
{   
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        // get values here 
        echo $this->request->data['start_time'];
        echo $this->request->data['end_time']; 
    }

}
```

**Update**
you've an error in your ajax,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/orders/hot_products",
    type: 'POST',

    data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to },
    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I got this error in Chrome console: POST .../orders/hot_products 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I fixed that, but it seems that it didnt get the data. It didnt show anything when I did that.
$from= $this->request->data['start_time'];        Debugger::dump($from);

Comment: no, it stays on the same page. I mean, instead of refreshing the page, I use ajax to avoid that.

Comment: whooops, error in your ajax call, it should be 
`data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to }
success: function(data){
 alert("success");
}`

Comment: oh yes, sorry. my bad. :D

Comment: It didnt work. it showed an error: unexpected identifier at alert("success"); And my response above is for your first answer. Because you posted double answers in a short time, my response was right after your second post. :D

Comment: missed `comma` at the end of data  `data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to },` pls check the update

Comment: I fixed the unexpected identifier, then it still doesnt work. follow this link http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8019/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products you can see my page. account is: admin@hotmail.com and pass is 123456. After login, please access the link above again.

Comment: giving output like this `Array
(
    [start_time] => 03 December 2013
    [end_time] => 13 December 2013
)
<pre>'03 December 2013'</pre><pre>'13 December 2013'</pre>
`

Comment: @@ How could you check that? if it is like that, it will work.

Comment: actually nothing in Chrome console, but POST 200 OK in Firefox console and I got success message. However, I cant see something like Array ( [start_time] => 03 December 2013 [end_time] => 13 December 2013 ) <pre>'03 December 2013'</pre><pre>'13 December 2013'</pre>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42341/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-tung-pham)

Answer (score 3):

If you method is **POST**:

```
 if($this->request->is('ajax'){
$this->request->data['start_time'];
$this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

**OR**

```
public function somefunction(){  
$this->request->data['start_time'];  
$this->autoRender = false;
```

ANd if method is **GET**:

```
 if($this->request->is('ajax'){
$this->request->query('start_time');
$this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

**OR**

```
public function somefunction(){  
$this->request->query('start_time');  
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Comment: it's kind of similar to what I did above. I mean the second way of POST method

Comment: If you use second way of both method, you can get result in same view file from where you called action. If you use first action, you have to create another ctp . e.g. for `public function someone` you have to make file `someone.ctp` files.

Comment: the second method, you mean, is the GET method or the second way of POST method? Any way, I want it to stay on the same view.

Comment: You can test it here. http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8019/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products
pick some dates and hit the submit button. When the submit button is hit, it will execute something like: $from= $this->request->data['start_time'];  Debugger::dump($from);