# Retrieving $_POST in jQuery .post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have a select with some values.

When an option is selected I need to use `.post` in jQuery to send the selected value to a PHP function to obtain the `$_POST` variable on PHP.

Then I can use the variable to evaluate a condition on PHP.

I use CakePHP 2 to create a URL.

To assing the post URL to the `numberOption` variable.

```
                $( "#selectFilter" ).change(function() {
  var numberOption = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'returnNumberOption/' ));?>" + 
  "/" + $( "#selectFilter option:selected" ).val();

  $.post(numberOption, function(data){
    console.log("Here is the number value of the select "+data);
    var phpVariable = "<?php echo $_POST?>"//THIS DONT WORK!
  });
});
```

Using this code I get an `unexpected identifier` error.

**Question**

How can I get the `$_POST` variable within the jQuery `$.post` call?

Comment: did you try to use ajax instead of post ?

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, not a single value.

Comment: I tried with print_r($_POST) and didnt work either.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327049/how-to-retrieve-data-sent-by-ajax-in-cakephp

Comment: I have attempted to extract some meaning out of the words that you dumped onto the page but it is impossible to make sense of it all. If you do not take the time to edit this into a higher quality question you are running the real risk of having it deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var url = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'returnNumberOption/' ));?>"; 
    var value = $( "#selectFilter option:selected" ).val();

     $.post(url,{data: value})
        .done(function(data){
        console.log("Here is the number value of the select "+data);
        var phpVariable = "<?php echo $_POST?>"//THIS DONT WORK!
    });

<?php
public function returnNumberOption() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
    }
}
```