# Can't get data from AJAX request in CakePHP 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

Javascript is working and when i visit `histories/history`. The `alert` shows `'succes'`. Please help me if you can.

```
function sendFPost(){
    var hello = "Hello World";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/untitled/histories/history',
        data: hello,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}

sendFPost();
```

```php
public function history()
{
    print_r($this->request->data);
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327049/how-to-retrieve-data-sent-by-ajax-in-cakephp

Comment: try: data: 'hello' for start, then try sending a JSON, like M14's link suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest using json requests:

*Ajax request:*

```
function sendFPost(){
var name = 'abc';
var email = 'abc@gmail.com';
var phone = 1234;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/untitled/histories/history.json', // json request
    data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
 });
}
sendFPost();
```

*In controller:*

```
public function history()
{
  if($this->request->is('post')) {
     $data = $this->request->data;
     $this->set([
        'data'=>$data,
        '_serialize'=>'data' // this will appear within success of ajax
     ]);
  }
}
```

And you might need to enable json extension in routes if you have not done previously.

*For details:*

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#jsonp-responses

Comment: Thanx so much for your answer) It almost solve my problem, but I have to send a value of my JS variable to the PHP and do some manipulation with it. Can you help me again please?

Comment: I think you have already done that.But still I have updated the answer.